# NLP Named Entity Recognition using NLTK and Spacy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I used the NER for the following sentence on both NLTK and Spacy and below are the results:

```
"Zoni I want to find a pencil, a eraser and a sharpener"
```

I ran the following code on Google Colab.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

ex = "Zoni I want to find a pencil, a eraser and a sharpener"

def preprocess(sent):
    sent = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    sent = nltk.pos_tag(sent)
    return sent

sent = preprocess(ex)
sent

#Output:
[('Zoni', 'NNP'),
 ('I', 'PRP'),
 ('want', 'VBP'),
 ('to', 'TO'),
 ('find', 'VB'),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('pencil', 'NN'),
 (',', ','),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('eraser', 'NN'),
 ('and', 'CC'),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('sharpener', 'NN')]
```

But when i used spacy on the same text, it didn't return me any result

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

text = "Zoni I want to find a pencil, a eraser and a sharpener"

doc = nlp(text)
doc.ents

#Output:
()
```

Its only working for some sentences.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

# text = "Zoni I want to find a pencil, a eraser and a sharpener"

text = 'European authorities fined Google a record $5.1 billion on Wednesday for abusing its power in the mobile phone market and ordered the company to alter its practices'

doc = nlp(text)
doc.ents

#Output:
(European, Google, $5.1 billion, Wednesday)
```

Please let me know if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Spacy* models are statistical. So the named entities that these models recognize are dependent on the data sets that these models were trained on.

According to *spacy* documentation a named entity is a “*real-world object*” that’s assigned a name – for example, a person, a country, a product or a book title.

For example, the name *Zoni* is not common, so the model doesn't recognize the name as being a named entity (person). If I change the name *Zoni* to *William* in your sentence *spacy* recognize *William* as a person.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp('William I want to find a pencil, a eraser and a sharpener')

for entity in doc.ents:
  print(entity.label_, ' | ', entity.text)
  #output
  PERSON  |  William
```

One would assume that *pencil*, *eraser* and *sharpener* are objects, so they would potentially be classified as products, because *spacy*  [documentation](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities) states 'objects' are products.  But that does not seem to be the case with the 3 objects in your sentence.

I also noted that if no named entities are found in the input text then the output will be empty.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

doc = nlp('Zoni I want to find a pencil, a eraser and a sharpener')
if not doc.ents:
  print ('No named entities were recognized in the input text.')
else:
  for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.label_, ' | ', entity.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the comparison you're trying to make. In your first example with NLTK, you're looking at the **POS tags** in the sentence. However in the second example with spaCy, you're looking at the **Named Entities**. These are two different things. The statistical models should always give you a POS tag per token (though it sometimes may be different), but the recognition of named entities (as explained in the post by 'Life is complex'), depend on the data sets that these models were trained on. If the models "feel like" there is no Named Entity in the sentence, you'll get an empty result set. But to get a fair comparison, you should also show the named entities found by NLTK, and compare with that.

If instead you wanted to compare POS tags, with spaCy you can run this:

```
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_)
```

Comment: I noted this difference too.  I glad that you mentioned the differences between the NLTK and spaCy code in the OP's question.